# How can I select a particular button (out of many buttons) in a page after a JSON/AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Sorry if the question was not clear.

Basically I have a voting system. I want the button the user clicks on to change its class value after the request has finished. Within `request.done(function(){CHANGE BUTTON'S CLASS VALUE})`.

So far I am only able to change the attribute on all buttons, and not only the button the user has clicked on.

Here is the code I have now:

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".vote", function (event) {
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("href"),
            dataType: 'json'
        });

        event.preventDefault();

        //My problem START
        request.done(function (data) {
            $('.vote button').attr('class', 'btn btn-primary btn-sm');
        });
        //My problem END

        request.fail(function (data) {
            alert("Voting failed!");
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<a class="vote" href="<?php base_url(); ?>vote/like/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span style="font-size: 3em" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
    </button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this)` doesn't have a reference to `$('.vote')` instance inside your `done()` promise. Cache the reference at the top of the event handler:

```
$(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".vote", function (event) {
        var $this = $(this);

        // ...

        request.done(function (data) {
            $this.children('button').attr('class', 'btn btn-primary btn-sm');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If you already have the button clicked in `$this` variable, why do you need to use `getElementsByTagName("button")`? No need, am I right? Plus, for changing classes `toggleClass()` function comes in handy.

Comment: Makes sense, but I still get an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ` in the console

Comment: @lesssugar good catch missed that in the copy/paste - Jeromie check the update

Comment: Great it works. How come you chose .children() instead of the good old .getElementsByTagName()?

Comment: Because `$this` is a jQuery object and doesn't have the function `getElementsByTagName()`  :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
$(function() {
$("body").on("click", ".vote", function (event) {
    var clicked = this;  // save pointer to the clicked button
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        dataType: 'json'
    });
    event.preventDefault();

    //My problem START
    request.done(function (data) {
        $(clicked).attr('class', 'btn btn-primary btn-sm');
    });
    //My problem END

    request.fail(function (data) {
        alert("Voting failed!");
    });
});
```

Comment: I get a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ` in the console

Comment: That's weird. I've test the code on my local on it works fine. Earlier I got 'parseerror' since the returned data is not JSON.

Comment: May be you can test it by commenting the `datatype: 'json'` first ?  Please note that I've fixed my code above, `datatype: 'json',` is changed to `datatype: 'json'`

Comment: I think the `,` after `datatype: 'json'` is causing the `request` to have `undefined` value. Mistake is on me.